# Copenhagen to Sweden non-rebookable train ticket validity

Tags: trains, tickets, sweden, copenhagen

I'll be taking the train from Copenhagen airport into Sweden. There are ticket machines in the airport but sometimes the lines are very long so I'm considering buying the ticket online at https://www.sj.se/

I know that I will take the train on that particular day but depending on when the flight comes in it may be an hour earlier or later.The cheapest fare class is called "non-rebookable". Is that ticket valid for the whole day or ONLY for a the specific time slot as booked?

The conditions seem unclear on this point

> Non-rebookable Tickets in this flexibility category cannot be
>   rebooked. The price you paid for your ticket will not be refunded and
>   the ticket cannot be transferred to another person. If, on the other
>   hand, you are unable to travel due to sickness, you will receive a
>   refund on presentation of a medical certificate.

Comment: Why don't you buy the ticket online when you have landed in Copenhagen and know which train you will be able to catch?

Comment: Not sure I'm going to have international data getting off the plane

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on which train you're selecting.

For the trains billed as *"SJ Snabbtåg"* the ticket is usually only valid for a particular train.

However SJ also sells tickets for the local/regional *Øresundståg*. Tickets for these departing from Copenhagen Airport (and other stations in central Copenhagen) are valid for departures within ±3 hours of the nominal departure time. (https://www.oresundstag.se/information/rese-och-kopvillkor/ in Swedish).

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Ticket bought !